# Closing open file without killing the process

Tags: linux, java, process, gdb, lsof

I have java(yeah java...) application running on CentOS 7.
After a while, there are many "deleted" files that bother me.

for deleted files used(not the issue):

```
lsof | grep "(deleted)"
```

I found them in /proc/pid/fd/... and my question is how can I kill/delete them without killing the process(process have to run 24/7).

I saw on google that I can use gdb tool, but I don't know how to use it.
Can you please help me(just to write step-by-step manual)?

I will love to hear some other suggestions if you have.

Comment: @user20574 If another program was writing to the file, and it lost the handle to it, it's obvious that would cause a file corruption.

Comment: @Glimpse well yes, but only to the file you force-closed. It's not obvious that it will also corrupt *other files at random*.

Comment: I am more curious about how to NOT make this happen in the first place. That is to ask: how to delete files properly in Java so they don't end up appearing as "deleted" but "open" files that you need to "clean up" separately.

Answer (score 19):

use `lsof -p $PID` and find the file descriptor (4th column)

`root@blah:~# lsof -p 1737 | grep "(deleted)"
apache2 1737 root    6w   REG    0,25        0  207401  (deleted)/var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log`

4th column is 6w, meaning file descriptor 6 and it was opened for writing (w).

Then:

`gdb -p $PID
p close($FD)`

eg:

`gdb -p 1737
.....
(gdb) p close(6)
$1 = 0
...
Quit anyway? (y or n) y
Detaching from program: /usr/lib/apache2/mpm-prefork/apache2, process 1737`

Comment: THANKS, finally a good working simple answer!!
btw, all my processes has 'x'u in 4th column.
What does "u" means?

Comment: `u` means that the file descriptor is opened reading and writing

Comment: `'close' has unknown return type; cast the call to its declared return type` comes up after `p close(x)`. Any idea how to do it? (p.s. running on CentOS 8)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command to find the deleted files file descriptors and you may truncate them afterwards

find /proc/ -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 \
-regex '/proc/[1-9][0-9]*/fd/[1-9][0-9]*' -type l -lname '*(deleted)' \
-printf '%p\n     %l\n' 2>/dev/null

Comment: But if the program still has the file descriptor opened, it may continue writing on these, growing disk space utilization